# What is the expected value of max value?

Tags: probability-distributions, expected-value

The expected value for $y(x)$ according to $x$ is as follows.

$\int_0^R f(x) y(x) dx$

where $0 < x < R$ and $f(x)$ is PDF for $x$.

But it is mean of $y(x)$ for all $x$.

I want to find the max values of $y(x)$ for $x$, not mean.

How can I find it?

Comment: So is $y(x)$ a function which returns a set of values?  $$\mathsf E(y(X))=\int_0^R f(x)~\max( y(x) )~\mathrm d x$$

Comment: If $y(x)$ have some variables for a $x$, you are right. But, typically, $y(x)$ is a fixed function for a $x$ and so, I think that the variance is used to find that.

Comment: So what maximum are you looking for?

Comment: For example, $y(x)$ is a probability that an accident occurs, according a value $x$. The probability decreases according to increasing $x$. Since $y(x)$ is probability, the expected value problem is easily solved. But, although the expected value is low, the accident can occurs. So, I find the overall expected maximum probability that the accident occurs, for all $x$.